# Interpreting bytes received through serial port

Tags: python, python-2.7

In attempting to communicate with a stepper motor controller over a serial port with pyserial I am receiving something like this as a response `'/0\x03\r\n'`.

I need to be able to convert the `'\x03'` byte to binary, the part that has me confused is that and `'\x03'` is considered a single character of the string so I can't do anything like: `'\x03'[2:]` to get `'03'`.

How can I convert `'\x03'` to something usable such as: `00000011` or `'03'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x03` is Python's way of telling you that there is *one* byte at that part of the string that has a hexadecimal value of `03`, which is not a printable character. The first two characters *are* printable (hex 2F and hex 30, respectively, ASCII characters `/` and `0`) so Python used the ASCII characters they correspond with.

You can use `ord()` to turn that into an integer:

```
>>> ord('\x03')
3
```

You could use the [`bin()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin), or the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to turn that integer into a binary representation, with the `format()` function being the more flexible and versatile option:

```
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
>>> format(3, 'b')
'11'
>>> format(3, '08b')
'00000011'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ord` to get each character's numerical value.

```
>>> s = '/0\x03\r\n'
>>> [ord(c) for c in s]
[47, 48, 3, 13, 10]
>>> [ord(c) for c in s][2]
3
```